# Microsoft Register Server has stopped working error msg on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Tags: windows, windows-7, dll

Everytime after **after the logon** I get this error:

```
Microsoft Register Server has stopped working.

APPCRASH
regsvr32.exe
...
```

I've found some articles recommending setting the DEP for regsvr32.exe, but *it does not work for 64 bit version*. What more, I think it's not a solution, rather a workaround.

Do you have any idea how to get rid of it? Can I reinstall the server or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. 
I had to find the application causing this problem. I knew, that I have no application starting on startup, that's why I was sure that is one of system services.

(To view them: `Start->Run`  and type `msconfig`)

The point was: If I started my PC with all services disabled, there was no error !
In the `msconfig` windows in the **General tab**: select `Userdefined startup`  (or something like that - I got a german version)

In the tab **Services**: you have to find which service is causing this issue: I would say that you don't have to disable Microsoft services, that's why you can easily check 
`Hide MS services`. Now you have to check a service, save, restart your pc and wait if the error appears. If not, continue **until you find the corrupted service**.

You will laugh, but my problem was that the Asus Screensaver was causing this problem. (Much junk software was preinstaled by default on my Asus Laptop)

So to help you I would say, verify first those services coming from your manufacter and 3rd party services.

What now? Simply leave it disabled, or unistall it !

Hope this helps you !

Comment: Confirmed: The "Adobe Screensaver" was my problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had exactly this problem on a client's Win2008 server.

Not helped by Microsoft's *interesting* naming scheme...
The 64-bit Regsvr32.exe is in windows\system32
The 32-bit Regsvr32.exe is in windows\syswow64

If you try to add DEP exclusion to the 64-bit version, it tells you it can't.
But excluding the 32-bit version seems to have worked.  I'm concerned with comments elsewhere that this is a "workaround", and that it's masking a deeper problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenation and getting rid of a number of unnecessary processes before finding the right one, I finally got rid of it on my spanking new 64 bit Asus by unticking AFBAgent in the services tab of msconfig. Some kind of fast boot software it didn't seem to make any difference to performance ditching t.

Comment: Thanx tpb,
The first one i tried to get rid of this problem was AFBAgent and it worked.
(Brand new asus laptop with win 7 64bit home premium)